# Formatting String in JAVA and EMAIL

Tags: java, string, string-formatting

I have formatted a report and saved it in a String like below..

[image]

I am trying to send an email using Javax.mail of this content. However, the String gets messed up and doesn't look like this when I get the email.

is there a way to have the String the same way as above and receive the email.

Here is the Email component I use to send email.
[image]

messageBody contains the String.

The messed up Report looks like this...

[image]

Comment: Please share the code where you send the mail with the String.

Comment: What does the messed up mail look like?

Comment: FYI, for code people prefer if you paste the actual code, not a screenshot. This makes it easier to test your code and make changes. For your ASCII table, I think a screenshot is fine.

Comment: If you are sending it as HTML, you will have to include style, especially a monospaced font. At that point, you might as well use a Table.

Comment: To echo what Grayson just said, your Report isn't "messed up"; it's just in a proportional font so nothing is lining up anymore.

Comment: I think it depends on the mail client whether a **text mail** is displayed with a monospaced font or a proportional font. You may try to send it as an html mail. (Which is more complicated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your `messageBody` like this:

```
messageBody = "<font face=\"courier new\" size=\"10px\">" + messageBody + "</font></p>";
message.setText(messageBody);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a sample, how to create an html mail:

```
    MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);

    //set from, recipient, subject ...

    //wrapper
    final MimeBodyPart wrap = new MimeBodyPart();

    //Text
    MimeMultipart cover = new MimeMultipart("alternative");
    BodyPart textPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    textPart.setContent(messageBody, "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
    textPart.setDisposition(Part.INLINE);
    cover.addBodyPart(textPart);

    //HTML
    BodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    htmlPart.setContent(messageBodyHtml, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
    htmlPart.setDisposition(Part.INLINE);
    cover.addBodyPart(htmlPart);

    wrap.setContent(cover);

    MimeMultipart content = new MimeMultipart("related");
    mimeMessage.setContent(content);
    content.addBodyPart(wrap);
```

The mail still contains a text part for those who have deactivated html mail. The variable `messageBodyHtml`contains the html code of the report table. It looks like this:

```
    <table>
        <tr><th>NAME</th><th>GENDER</th>...</tr>
        <tr><td>Eddy</td><td>Male</td>...</tr>
        .
        .
        .
    </table>
```

hope this helps.